# how to retrieve chat conversation from google Talk using c#?

Tags: c#

hiii i am working on window application using c#, i want to retrieve chat conversation from google Talk, how to do it?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page may help you: http://code.google.com/apis/talk/

Answer (score 0):

Some one is doing the same but for [yahoo](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/instantmessaging/comments.php/c6225/?thread=15297)